# Configuring the generated name of precompiled Handlebars templates

Tags: javascript, npm, handlebars.js

Is it possible to manually configure the name/index that gets generated when compiling Handlebars templates using the NPM package?

I’ve used Handlebars in different contexts (Rails, NodeJS, PHP) and I notice that in some cases, the generated template name is the basename of the file, whereas in other situations the name is the full path to the file.

For instance, running `handlebars app/templates/*.hbs -n HandlebarsTemplates -e hbs` will result in names like:

```
HandlebarsTemplates["my_template"]
```

But in other places, I’ve also seen the following:

```
HandlebarsTemplates["app/templates/my_template"]
```

I couldn’t find an option that could be passed to the `handlebars` script that controls this.

Is this configurable behaviour? Or is it a discrepancy between compiling in pure JS (calling `Handlebars.compile(source)`) vs using the CLI tool?

It would also be interesting to know which of these naming styles ends up closer to the recommended best practice for using Handlebars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is non obvious from the docs, but looking more closely at [the implementation](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/bin/handlebars#L169), I discovered that the template path/name can be switched by passing in an empty `--root` argument.

By default, the script calls `basename()`, which compiles to `my_template`:

```
 handlebars app/templates/my_template.hbs -e hbs
```

Whereas, passing in an empty `--root` argument will avoid converting the path, so the following command compiles to `app/templates/my_template`:

```
handlebars app/templates/my_template.hbs -e hbs -r
```